# Maple Command-Line on Ubuntu

Tags: maple

How to run a command using Maple Command-Line on Ubuntu.

When I run the following command through terminal:

```
/home/myuser/maple14/bin/maple -c 2+2
```

Maple runs as expected, but the command (2+2) is not calculated.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to execute commands from maple, without the greetings and if you want maple to exit after executing the command, the `-c` option is not the option you need. In fact you must feed maple with the commands (or with a file that contains your commands). For such a simple example, I would preferably do:

```
maple -q <<< '2+2;'
```

(dont forget the semicolon!). The `-q` option is to tell maple to keep quiet. The `<<<` is a bash here string. This is the equivalent of

```
echo '2+2;' | maple -q
```

(but as a bash user, I don't like this very much). As you'll notice, the answer is displayed as maple would display it (i.e., human readable, centered on a terminal line). Maybe you'd prefer to use the printf command:

```
maple -q <<< 'printf("%a\n",2+2);'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will find that both the input and output of such commands are not echoed, even when they are executed ok.

Does this work for you?

```
maple -c "print(2+2);"
```